# Reflect time zone selected by user on time stamps in Ruby application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone, timestamp

I want to make each of the time stamps on my ruby application according to the user selected time zone. I am new to ruby in rails so can't figure out how to do it.

I made drop down list appear for the user to select timezone from through

```
<%= time_zone_select( "user", 'time_zone', ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all, :default => "Beijing")%>
```

How to make the choice of time zone reflect on all the time stamps used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using a `before_filter` in `application_controller.rb` makes sure that this method is called every request.  The default timezone on every request is set by `config.time_zone` so you have to update `Time.zone` on every request.  look at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html

```
before_filter :set_user_timezone

def set_user_timezone
  if current_user && current_user.time_zone.present?
    Time.zone = current_user.time_zone
  end
end
```

to evaluate an expression using a particular timezone, use `Time.use_zone`

```
Time.use_zone('Singapore') do
  Time.zone.parse(...) # returns a time in Singapore
end
```

UPDATE: using `session` to save the timezone

```
# application_controller.rb
before_filter :set_user_timezone

def set_user_timezone
  Time.zone = session[:timezone] || 'Default timezone here'
end

# time_zone_controller.rb
def save_time_zone
  session[:timezone] = params[:timezone]
end

# routes
match 'save_time_zone' => 'time_zone#save_time_zone'

# js
$('#user_time_zone').change(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/save_time_zone',
    data: { time_zone: $(this).val() }
  })
})
```

Comment: i got undefined local variable or method `current_user'

Comment: replace `current_user` above with the method that you use to get the currenly logged in user.

Comment: ok....what if i don't have any user logged in ?? 
what should I use then?
Actually my application don't have any user sessions. I want to use this time zone utility so that any end user can see the timestamps of the changes he made in his timezone .

Comment: ok. i made that assumption because you used `:user` above.  If you don't have any users, you can probably use the session to save the selected time_zone. I'll update my answer if you want to do this

Comment: sorry I didn't mention that....yes please update the answer, as I am trying to achieve that only

Comment: thanks a lot for update.
I think i need to learn a lot in ruby on rails...

i now I got expected /time_zone_controller.rb to define TimeZoneController

Comment: I think i need much more code than just
def save_time_zone
  session[:timezone] = params[:timezone]
end
 in my save_time_zone.rb
thanks a lot again, any help would be welcomed even resources on how to quickly learn ruby on rails.
i am marking ur answer as accepted.

Comment: yes, you should at least have some basic understanding of Rails' MVC architecture.  I suggest you try ruby.railstutorial.org